# How to reverse the effect of backslash?

Tags: python

I am not really sure how to frame the question more appropriately, but the following example may illustrate what I need:

```
def func(prefix):
    prefix = prefix or ""
    some_name = prefix + "-" + "bar"
    print(some_name)
```

Suppose I call this function `func("foo")` the output will be `foo-bar` but when I call `func(None)` the output will be `-bar` and I would want something more like just `bar`.

Now obviously I could do write if conditions and tackle that. But, is there a pythonic way of doing that? It is more like the inverted version `\b`.

Then I could write something like

```
prefix = prefix or "\some_char"
```

that would do the magic.

Comment: To have the backslash from ```"\some_char"``` recognized as a backslash, you need to double it. Something like this: ```"\\some_char"```.

Comment: @accdias: no, they were hoping that `\b`, the backspace character, could somehow be used to remove the `-` from the string produced if `prefix` is `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Oh! Now I see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvotes. Yes there was a typo in the `bar`. Thanks for pointing that out @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.join()`, and filter out empty components:

```
def func(prefix):
    return '-'.join(filter(None, (prefix, 'bar')))
```

This works for empty strings too:

```
>>> def func(prefix):
...     return '-'.join(filter(None, (prefix, 'bar')))
...
>>> func(None)
'bar'
>>> func('foo')
'foo-bar'
>>> func('')
'bar'
```

A good alternative is to just use a conditional expression:

```
def func(prefix):
    return f"{prefix}-bar" if prefix else "bar"
```

Again, empty strings are treated the same as `None` there, use `if prefix is not None` if an empty string should result in `'-bar'`.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `-` in the effective prefix, not in the joining operation.

```
def foo(prefix=None):
    # prefix = prefix + "-" if prefix is not None else ""
    prefix += "-" if prefix else ""
    return prefix + "bar"
```

If you for whatever reason *want* an output like `"-bar"` in some circumstance, you can differentiate between no prefix and an empty prefix.

```
def foo(prefix=None):
    prefix += "-" if prefix is not None else ""
    return prefix + "bar"
```

In this case, `foo()` will produce `"bar"` while `foo("")` would produce `"-bar"`.

Comment: This ```prefix = prefix + "-" if prefix is not None else ""``` can be more Pythonic if written like ```prefix += "-" if prefix else ""```

Comment: Yeah, that's better.

Comment: I'm going to add a slightly longer version that allows for `foo(None)` to produce `"-bar"` in addition to `foo()` producting `"bar"`. (Not sure why anyone might *want* that, but it's an option).

Comment: I'm under the impression that the op wants something for path manipulation. If that's the case ```pathlib``` would be a better option.